# How can I create a screenshot of the browser with QF-Test?

Tags: screenshot, jython, qf-test

QF-Test allows me to take a screenshot of the whole desktop with:

```
from imagewrapper import ImageWrapper
iw = ImageWrapper(rc)
screenshot = iw.grabScreenshot()
```

How can I take a screenshot of only the browser?

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness:

1. If you are testing a Java application you can also use the `grabImage` function. This function works even when the component is hidden by another window. Unfortunately (until now), `grabImage` doesn't work for Web.

   ```
   from imagewrapper import ImageWrapper
   iw = ImageWrapper(rc)
   image = iw.grabImage(rc.getComponent("myComponentId")) # this methods also has some optional/additional parameters. In the qftest script editor, type iw. and then press Ctrl+Space to see the full "documentation".
   rc.logImage(image)
   ```
2. When using the script from Aaron Digulla, keep in mind, that the SUT window has to be in the foreground/visible on the screen.
   There are some options to ensure this [for example: "Raise SUT windows automatically" + event] (See: http://www.qfs.de/qftest/manual/en/opt_play.html). Keep in mind, that you can also change these options during runtime (See: http://www.qfs.de/qftest/manual/en/user_scripting.html#usec_scripting_options).

Comment: Edit: In newer QF-Test versions grabImage also work in other (=non Java) applications.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [DomNode API](http://www.qfs.de/qftest/manual/en/tech_dom_domnode.html#sec_dom_domnode) to get the geometry of a node in the DOM. You can use those to specify which are should be included in the screenshot:

```
from imagewrapper import ImageWrapper
import os.path

iw = ImageWrapper(rc)

# Get root node of the DOM
doc = rc.getComponent("genericDocument")
root = doc.getRootElement()
# Get the geometry (x,y,width,height)
geometry = root.getLocationOnScreen()
# Use the geometry to limit the screenshot
screenshot = iw.grabScreenshot(*geometry)

# Optional: Save the screenshot on disk.
# Use a gloabl variable to set the folder where screenshots should be collected
folder = rc.lookup("screenshotFolder") 
filename = os.path.join(folder, "name.png")
rc.logMessage('Saving screenshot as %s' % filename, report=True)
iw.savePng(filename, screenshot)

# Optional: Add screenshot to the log
rc.logImage(screenshot, "Login Screen", report=True)
```